# alternatives to Adobe PS Sketch, that work on macOS desktop

Tags: graphic-design, macos

I want to doodle every now and then and save my drawings.

Adobe Photoshop Sketch looks like a perfect app for me, unfortunately it's mobile-only.

I want an app that will run on my MacBook that:

- starts up fast
- is generally lightweight
- lets me create drawings
- doesn't require me to faff about with "new canvas", "100x100" dimensions etc. when making a new drawing
- lets me somehow archive/save drawings I create in a simple system

I prefer cheaper software but don't really care.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Then **[edit]** your question accordingly, and it can be reopened. E.g.: What features do you need? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Thanks, much better! Can you add the price tag as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app called [Sketchbook](https://sketchbook.com) that runs on the Mac. It is a pretty simple app with several different drawing tools and a blank canvas. This was a paid app but recently went free. Its by AutoDesk. There is also an iOS version that runs on iPads and iPhones.